# convert a encode value to string

Tags: string, format, encode, human-readable

Sample string :`<U+0424><U+0413><U+0411><U+0423> "<U+041D><U+0418><U+0414><U+041E><U+0418> <U+0438><U+043C>. <U+0413>.<U+0418>.<U+0422><U+0443><U+0440><U+043D><U+0435><U+0440><U+0430>`

Just wondering is there any online convertor or node module to convert this value to a readable string,
not sure whether it is Unicode or not

Please suggest a online convertor or node module to convert the string to readable format

Answer (score 0):

Here's a online conversion tool https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/. Copy into the U+Hex and click convert. The < and > symbols don't get converted. I get some intelligible Russian characters. It looks like the name of a children's hospital.